# Need password protection for post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, visibility, password-protection

Iam trying to protect my post using default Password protected in wordpress. Before clicking the post ask password for that post. After giving password needs to redirect to that post.

Comment: hey, you can make the password-protected post in the post itself. [Check Here](https://www.seedprod.com/password-protect-page-wordpress/)

Comment: Thanks for your sugession
actually we need password protection like this Title of the post, post image, then input field as a password. if this validation sucess needs to redirect to particular post.